# How to edit textures with texture paint in Cycles like GLSL in Blender internal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, texture-painting

When I edit my textures (color, spec, normal etc.) in cycles I can only see the texture that I am currently editing.

Sometimes when I edit one specific texture, e.g. when I edit the bumpmap, I want to see all the other textures to get the best result.

In blender internal it is possible by using GLSL shading. Is there a way to do that in cycles as well?

All textures are mixed with mix nodes. The last mix node is connected to a *Shader Output* node. Cycles renders everything correctly, therefore the node setup is okay. However, I cannot see all textures together in 3D View.

Can you help me?

Comment: Does setting the viewport shading to *Textured* work?

Comment: The material view port view displays different results than cycles renderer. Therefore i cannot use this for texture painting. Ambient occlusion seam to work, but no spec, norm and bump.

Comment: Texture view port only displays actual selected texture node of material node editor.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the viewport shading to [*Material*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Texture_Editing#3D_Viewport_Draw_Types), it will display image textures as mixed in the shader node setup:

[image]

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Texture_Editing#3D_Viewport_Draw_Types):

> *Material*: a simplified version of the entire material is drawn using
>   GLSL shaders. This uses solid lighting, and also is mostly useful for
>   editing, painting and mapping textures, but while seeing how they
>   integrate with the material.